# Typing the DOM ref in the vue.js typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I'm just wondering why my `ref` to a simple button won't work in typescript. I created a simple button and a constant and then when component is mounted I check if the ref is `null` or not. otherwise make the button un-disabled...

Here is the example code:

```
<template>
 <input v-model="phone" type="text" />
 <button ref="phoneSubmitBtn" type="button" disabled>تایید</button>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { Ref, ref, watch, onMounted } from 'vue';

const phoneSubmitBtn: Ref<HTMLButtonElement>|Ref<null> = ref(null);
let phone: Ref<string> | Ref<null> = ref(null);

onMounted(() => {
    if (phoneSubmitBtn.value === null) { 
        return false
    }

    watch(phone, () => {
        if (phone.value !== null && phone.value.length === 11) {
            phoneSubmitBtn.value.disabled = false;
        } else{
            phoneSubmitBtn.value.disabled = true;
        }
    })
})
</script>
```

**Note: Logic works fine and everything works as well but the `VSCODE` tells me that `phoneSubmitBtn.value.disabled: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)` inside of the watch section.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`phoneSubmitBtn` is incorrectly typed, it's narrowed down to `Ref<null>` on assignment because it's a constant, so the type of `phoneSubmitBtn.value` is `null`.

It should have been:

```
const phoneSubmitBtn: Ref<HTMLButtonElement | null> = ref(null);
```

Since `ref` a generic, variable type can be inferred:

```
const phoneSubmitBtn = ref<HTMLButtonElement | null>(null);
```